# Number of paths?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Hi need help with this question I don't know what to do?

Let $m \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$ be integers. Consider a rectangle whose 
horizontal side has length $m$ and whose vertical side has length $n$. 
A path from the bottom-left corner to the top-right corner is called 
$valid$, if in each step, it either goes one unit to the right or 
one unit upwards.

How many valid paths are there? Justify your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let *u* be one unit upwards, *r* one unit to the right. If $m=7$ and $n=2$, a sequence like *rrurrurrr* is a valid path. There are $\binom{n+m}{m} = \binom{n+m}{n} $ different such paths.

If you can take diagonals, it is called [Delannoy number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delannoy_number).